# REGEX re.compile a string into a group in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a string using`re.compile`.

The string in question is formatted as such:

```
"Sq123ABCd_A010_Department_v01.0101.exr"
```

using re.compile I'd like to return this

```
('Sq123ABCd_A010','_Department_','v01.','0101','.exr'')
```

I have this so far:

```
match = re.compile('^(.*?)(\S)(\d+)\.(.*?)$').match(fname)
match.group()
```

which returns:

```
('Sq030ION_S010_Lighting_', 'v', '002', '0101.exr')
```

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO. Could you edit the formatting of your post please? It's hard to read when it's all just plain text.

Comment: Just edited the post!

Comment: I try to avoid regex most of the time since it's not readable. Using the string functions especially split and join I can usually parse strings with no problems and it's much easier than regex.

Comment: thx Sriram for editing the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
In [208]: text = 'Sq123ABCd_A010_Department_v01.0101.exr'

In [231]: baseName, dept, version, frameNum, fileType = re.findall(r'(.*?_.*?)_(.*)_(.*?\.)(.*?)(\..*)', text)[0]

In [232]: baseName, dept, version, frameNum, fileType
Out[232]: ('Sq123ABCd_A010', 'Department', 'v01.', '0101', '.exr')
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED  thx  you for your suggestion. the problem with using re.finall is it returns a list inside a group. what I would like to do is something more like this

' match = re.compile(REGEX).match(fname)'
'baseName, dept, version, frameNum, fileType = match.groups()'
'match.groups()'

Comment: @laplant76 Edited.

Comment: @COLDSPEED  thx  you for your suggestion. the problem with using re.finall is it returns a list inside a group. what I would like to do is something more like this

' match = re.compile(REGEX).match(fname)'
'baseName, dept, version, frameNum, fileType = match.groups()'
'match.groups()'

returns

'('Sq030ION_S010', 'Lighting', 'v002.', '0101', '.exr')'

where

'print baseName'

returns

'Sq030ION_S010'

Comment: also. again, my apologies. not sure how to format my posts so they are more readable

Comment: @laplant76 When you have a working solution, massaging it to fit your specifics really isn't all that hard. You should try to figure out how to do these things yourself than declare the solution useless. ;) Anyway, look at my edit.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thx you again. And my apologies. I was not suggesting your solution was useless. I apologize if it came across that way. I in no way want to insult, or dismiss anyone's  help and/or suggestions. I do appreciate your input, and welcome your suggestions. thx you again :)